# Is it possible to run AppArmor in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apparmor

I am new to AWS . I want to setup a sandbox in AWS linux. So easiest way , I could find was to use pre-built components like AppArmor or SELinux.

But I couldn't find any articles relating whether AWS supports AppArmor or not ?

Pls help me with this ?

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AWS supports both AppArmor and SELinux.  AppArmor provides [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) implemented using [LSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules).  All of this is done in the kernel, which is something you control on EC2 (you can even specify custom kernels, though that is unnecessary for this exercise).

You shouldn't need anything special to setup AppArmor on EC2 -- though implementing these type of protections is challenging enough on its own!

An easier route for sandboxing would be setting up [chroot jails](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot).  Chroot jails are much more common than mandatory access controls and may be more than enough security for your use-case.  They're also used extensively on EC2.